Add button in toolbar to perform some processing on data (matplotlib)
I have the following code which plots a time-series. I can spanselect inside the upper subplot which applies some processing when pressing the 'z' key and displays this new data inside the lower subplot. Moreover, it is possible to go back to the initial upper plot of the data when clicking on the 'Home' button in the toolbar.
I would like to add a new button to the toolbar, named "Process", which will perform the same operation as pressing the 'z' key when clicked by the user. The key press functionality can be dropped if it simplifies the implementation.
Code:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import SpanSelector
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

if __name__ == '__main__':
    idx = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", "2018-01-03", freq="10s")
    df = pd.DataFrame(range(len(idx)), index=idx, columns=['val_phys'])

    date_min = df.index.values[0]
    date_max = df.index.values[len(df) - 1]

    # Display non-overlapping layout
    plt.rcParams['figure.constrained_layout.use'] = True
    # Use concise dates for labels
    plt.rcParams['date.converter'] = 'concise'
    # Display grid
    plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
    tb = fig.canvas.toolbar

    ax1.plot(df)
    # We scale the x-axis to the scale of the data (for Windows)
    ax1.set_xlim([mdates.date2num(date_min), mdates.date2num(date_max)])
    # For aesthetics we set the second plot axes
    ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())

    # We push this scale onto the stack of the toolbar
    tb.push_current()

    def on_select(xmin, xmax):
        global date_min, date_max

        date_min = mdates.num2date(xmin).replace(tzinfo = None)
        date_max = mdates.num2date(xmax).replace(tzinfo = None)

        ax1.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
        visible_y = df.loc[(df.index >= date_min) & (df.index <= date_max)].val_phys
        if len(visible_y):
            ax1.set_ylim(min(visible_y), max(visible_y))
        ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
        tb.push_current()
        plt.draw()

    def on_key(event):
        #print('you pressed', event.key, event.xdata, event.ydata)
        if event.key == 'z':
            # We filter dataframe to selected date range by mouse
            df_selected = df.loc[(df.index >= date_min) & (df.index <= date_max)]

            # We only keep one sample every 5 minutes (5*6=30 10-seconds samples)
            df_selected = df_selected.iloc[::30]

            ax2.clear()
            ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
            ax2.plot(df_selected)
            ax2.autoscale(enable=True, axis="y", tight=False)
            plt.draw()

    span_selector = SpanSelector(ax1, on_select, direction='horizontal', useblit=True)
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_key)

    plt.show()

I have tried to adapt the examples given in the Tool Manager documentation without success.

OK I found a solution in the following code.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import SpanSelector
from matplotlib.backend_tools import ToolBase
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

matplotlib.rcParams["toolbar"] = "toolmanager"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    idx = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", "2018-01-03", freq="10s")
    df = pd.DataFrame(range(len(idx)), index=idx, columns=['val_phys'])

    class Process(ToolBase):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.toggle_flag = False  # Initial state

        def trigger(self, sender, event, data=None):
            self.toggle_flag = True  # Toggle state
            if self.toggle_flag:
                # We filter dataframe to selected date range by mouse
                df_selected = df.loc[(df.index >= date_min) & (df.index <= date_max)]

                # We only keep one sample every 5 minutes (5*6=30 10-seconds samples)
                df_selected = df_selected.iloc[::30]

                ax2.clear()
                ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
                ax2.plot(df_selected.drop(columns=['cq']))
                ax2.set_ylabel(labels[meta['unite_phys']])
                ax2.autoscale(enable=True, axis="y", tight=False)
                plt.draw()

                self.toggle_flag = False

    date_min = df.index.values[0]
    date_max = df.index.values[len(df) - 1]

    # Display non-overlapping layout
    plt.rcParams['figure.constrained_layout.use'] = True
    # Use concise dates for labels
    plt.rcParams['date.converter'] = 'concise'
    # Display grid
    plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
    #tb = fig.canvas.toolbar
    tm = fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager
    tm.add_tool("Process", Process)
    fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.add_tool(tm.get_tool("Process"), "toolgroup")

    ax1.plot(df.drop(columns = ['cq']))
    # We scale the x-axis to the scale of the data (for Windows)
    ax1.set_xlim([mdates.date2num(date_min), mdates.date2num(date_max)])
    ax1.set_ylabel(labels[meta['unite_phys']])
    ax1.set_title(meta['ncon'])
    # For aesthetics we set the second plot axes
    ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())

    # We push this scale onto the stack of the toolbar
    #tb.push_current()

    def on_select(xmin, xmax):
        global date_min, date_max

        date_min = mdates.num2date(xmin).replace(tzinfo = None)
        date_max = mdates.num2date(xmax).replace(tzinfo = None)
        vprint(f"Selected Span: xmin={date_min}, xmax={date_max}")

        ax1.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
        visible_y = df.loc[(df.index >= date_min) & (df.index <= date_max)].val_phys
        if len(visible_y):
            ax1.set_ylim(min(visible_y), max(visible_y))
        ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
        #tb.push_current()
        plt.draw()

    def on_key(event):
        #print('you pressed', event.key, event.xdata, event.ydata)
        if event.key == 'z':
            # We filter dataframe to selected date range by mouse
            df_selected = df.loc[(df.index >= date_min) & (df.index <= date_max)]

            # We only keep one sample every 5 minutes (5*6=30 10-seconds samples)
            df_selected = df_selected.iloc[::30]

            ax2.clear()
            ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
            ax2.plot(df_selected.drop(columns=['cq']))
            ax2.set_ylabel(labels[meta['unite_phys']])
            ax2.autoscale(enable=True, axis="y", tight=False)
            plt.draw()

    span_selector = SpanSelector(ax1, on_select, direction='horizontal', useblit=True)
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_key)

    plt.show()

The problem lies in the fact that I had to comment calls to tb.push_current() method and thus the 'Home', 'Forward' & 'Backward' buttons do not work anymore.
Any clue on how can it be fixed with Tool Manager, please ?
